# How to print the picture of any size to full A4 page in VB NET?

Tags: vb.net

I have image of any size (eg 100x100 pixels) and I need to print stretched to the fixed size A4 (210 x 297 MM - mm, not pixels..)

How to print the picture of any size to full A4 page in VB NET?

Sample code:

```
  Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    Dim newMargins As System.Drawing.Printing.Margins
    newMargins = New System.Drawing.Printing.Margins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = newMargins

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(picSource.Image, 0, 0)
End Sub


Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    PrintDocument1.Print()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Rectangle and draw the image to that with this Overload for the `DrawImage` method. Change the x,y and size as needed.

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
 Dim newMargins As System.Drawing.Printing.Margins
 newMargins = New System.Drawing.Printing.Margins(0, 0, 0, 0)
 PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = newMargins
 Dim ImgRect As New Rectangle(0,0,100,100)
 e.Graphics.DrawImage(picSource.Image, ImgRect)
End Sub
```

Comment: ok, but " ... New Rectangle( ... " parametters is in pixels. I need to set up the size in millimeters.
image size in pixels is not important, i need set up size in millimeters and stretch image to full A4 size..

Comment: You can check the page for it's width and height which are in pixels and just the rectangle accordingly.